# How to get bootstrap with native variables?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to get a build of a bootstrap library that uses native CSS variables. In this case, the class used a variable from `:root`

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: var(--primary)!important;
}
```

instead of a static color:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: #007bff!important;
}
```

How do I compile such a library?

Comment: Bootstrap4 comes with the dynamic variables. You don't need to compile it again to get the defaults used in the Bootstrap.

Comment: There is issue in github about this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26596

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything if you want to use the default dynamic variables of bootstrap in bootstrap-4. Example:

```css
.primary{
     color: var(--primary)!important;
}
.danger{
     color: var(--danger)!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<h2 class="primary">Example body text</h2>
<p class="danger">Nullam quis risus eget <a href="#">urna mollis ornare</a> vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula.</p>
```